# jQuery Validation Plugin works for some rules but ignores others

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am having problems getting the validation plugin to recognize that all my input tags and text area need to be required.  It is validating the email field but no others.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#contactForm').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 1
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        subject: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 1
        },
        message: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 1
        }
    }
});
});
```

And here is the html of the page I am trying to validate

```
<form id="contactForm" action="./gdform.php" method="post">

        <div id="formSection">
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="./thankyou.html" />
            <div id="topSection">
                <label><input type="text" id="Name" name="name" value="Name" required /></label>
                <label><input type="text" id="Email" name="email" value="Email" required /></label>
            </div>
            <div id="messageSection">
                <label><input id="Subject" type="text" name="subject" value="Subject" /></label>
                <label><textarea name="message" rows="6" required>Message</textarea></label>

                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Here is a fiddle so you can see my issue http://jsfiddle.net/mM62X/ .
Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems is, you are adding default value all input elements instead of using placeholder. Since you have a value in the input element the required validation will pass hence there is no validation error.

```
<form id="contactForm" action="./gdform.php" method="post">
    <div id="formSection">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="./thankyou.html" />
        <div id="topSection">
            <label>
                <input type="text" id="Name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required />
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="text" id="Email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div id="messageSection">
            <label>
                <input id="Subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
            </label>
            <label>
                <textarea name="message" rows="6" required placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </label>
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/796xZ/)

Note: It is not supported < IE 10

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't realize that haha.  No wonder the plugin worked for me on other projects where I didn't put a default value in my input tags!